# Какие элементы первого  массива и сколько раз встречаются во втором массиве

Tags: массивы, c

Даны два массива разных размеров. Определить, какие элементы первого
массива и сколько раз встречаются во втором массиве. На языке Си

Comment: >Определить, какие элементы первого массива и сколько раз встречаются во втором массиве. На языке Си

и побыстрее?

Comment: ахахах, +1

Comment: >было бы неплохо

@Arts1995 своим комментарием я вам намекнул, что ваш вопрос был составлен некорректно, поскольку здесь не приветствуется решение учебных задач за учащихся. Более того, очень невежливо писать свой вопрос в виде приказных формулировок, как это написано у вас - здесь никто никому ничем не обязан и не должен. Если хотите, чтобы вам помогли с вашей задачей, то переформулируйте ваш вопрос более правильно и опишите, что вы сделали сами, и что не получилось

Comment: @Arts1995, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. решение : сделать две таблицы *SQL* по значениям из массива, сделать **LEFT JOIN**,а дальше все просто.
2. решение : сначала отсортировываете два массива(лексикографически для символьного), пото итераторами проходите по каждому из них, одновременно сравнивая соответствующие элементы.Процесс сравнения задая элементарная.

Comment: От того что выше сказанное, я ничего не понял((

Comment: господин, вы пьяны? можно проше и быстрее.

Comment: интересно, при чем тут вообще SQL и итераторы, если речь идет о старом добром Си?

Comment: ой, простите. Я думал вы пишете на *Java\C#\C++*.
Если *Си* то делайте по 2 решению. Вместо итераторов - обычные ссылки.

Comment: Юмор - он такой, не каждому дано...

Comment: А еще можно (если памяти не жалко) сделать хэш-таблицу из второго массива (один проход) и поискать в ней элементы первого (тоже один проход).

Answer (score 0):

Да простят меня модераторы, но. Вот так не пойдёт?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct {
    int val;
    int numb;
} s;

void sort(int arr[], int n) {
    int i, flag = 1, j=1;
    while(flag) {
        flag = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < n-j; i++)
            if(arr[i] > arr[i+1]) {
                flag = 1;
                int t = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i+1];
                arr[i+1] = t;
            }
        j++;
    }
}

int search(s arr[], int n, int val) {
    int a = 0, b = n-1;
    if(val == arr[a].val) return a;
    if(val == arr[b].val) return b;
    if(val < arr[a].val) return -1;
    if(val > arr[b].val) return -1;
    while(b - a > 1) {
        int i = (a+b)/2;
        if(val == arr[i].val) return i;
        else if(val < arr[i].val) b = i;
        else a = i;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main() {
    int n1, n2, n3, *arr1, *arr2, i, i1;
    s *arr3;
    printf("Введите размер первого массива:");
    scanf("%d", &n1);
    arr1 = malloc(sizeof(int)*n1);
    printf("Введите первый массив:");
    for(i = 0; i < n1; i++) scanf("%d", arr1+i);
    for(i = 0; i < n1; i++) printf("%d ", arr1[i]);
    putchar('\n');
    printf("Введите размер второго массива:");
    scanf("%d", &n2);
    arr2 = malloc(sizeof(int)*n2);
    printf("Введите второй массив:");
    for(i = 0; i < n2; i++) scanf("%d", arr2+i);
    for(i = 0; i < n2; i++) printf("%d ", arr2[i]);
    putchar('\n');
    sort(arr1, n1);
    for(i = 1, n3 = 1; i < n1; i++) if(arr1[i-1] != arr1[i]) n3++;
    arr3 = malloc(sizeof(s)*n3);
    bzero(arr3, sizeof(s)*n3);
    for(i=0, i1=0; i<n1; i++)
        if(!i || arr1[i] != arr1[i-1]) arr3[(i1++)].val = arr1[i];
    for(i=0; i<n2; i++) 
        if((i1 = search(arr3, n3, arr2[i])) >= 0) arr3[i1].numb++;
    for(i=0; i<n3; i++)
        printf("%10d:%5d\n", arr3[i].val, arr3[i].numb);
    free(arr3);
    free(arr1);
    free(arr2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @alexlz как вам не стыдно

Comment: @DreamChild мне стыдно